# SCRecorder video player unable to play file after saving

Tags: ios, iphone, video, swift, parse-platform

I have configured SCRecorder to allow me to create a video file and upload this file to Parse as a PFFile. I have checked to make sure the file is saved properly by opening it on my computer. My problem is with trying play the video back to a video player after querying the file from parse. I have tried using both SCImageView as well as SCVideoPlayerView to present the video, but neither is working.

Using storyboards, I've created the player with a UIView of subclass SCImageView, set the background to clear and declared a property for SCPlayer.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: SCImageView!
    var player: SCPlayer?
```

Here is my viewDidLoad

```
    videoPlayerView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    videoPlayerView.filterGroup = nil

    player = SCPlayer()
    player?.CIImageRenderer = videoPlayerView
    player?.loopEnabled = true
```

After getting the video object I use the PFFile and get the URL to set the item

```
    let videoFile = video.objectForKey("videoFile") as PFFile

    var videoURLString = videoFile.url
    var videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLString)

    player?.setItemByUrl(videoURL)
    player?.play()
```

I tried a similar method using SCVideoPlayerView and its initialized SCPlayer instead of SCImageView. Any solution using this library is appreciated as well as other alternatives to playing looping videos. Thanks

Comment: I believe the problem is that my videoURL is linked to the video file as raw data, and I then try to set an AVPlayer with this videoURL and the AVPlayer cannot be set with this url to raw data. If this is my problem, is there a way to set an AVPlayer using raw data? Or alternatively, is there a way to save the file to Parse without compressing it to raw data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue... I just needed to use PFFile(data: data, contentType: "video/mp4") :P.

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of this videoURLString? If you are referencing to a file URL like "/Users/user/something.mp4" you will want to use NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoURLString) instead.

Comment: I think problem is that the file URL is formatted as "h ttp://files.parsetfss.com/something-file".